# Bulk Load with commas in columns causing truncation errors

Tags: sql-server-2014, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk import a `.CSV` file with 13 columns into SQL Server using Management Studio 2014 with the following script and am encountering truncation issues:

```
CREATE TABLE #BudgetPlan 
(
     BUSINESS_UNIT VARCHAR(50), 
     DEPT VARCHAR(50), 
     JOBCODE VARCHAR(50), 
     FISCAL_YEAR VARCHAR(4), 
     FISCAL_MN VARCHAR(3),
     REG_HOURS DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     OT_HOURS DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     CONTRACT_HOURS DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     NON_PROD_HOURS DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     REG_SAL DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     OT_SAL DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     CONTRACT_DOL DECIMAL(10, 2), 
     NONPROD_SAL DECIMAL(10, 2)
)

BULK INSERT #BudgetPlan 
FROM '\\nt115\TESTING\Consolidated Hours Dollars.csv' 
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

I get some errors:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 4 (FISCAL_YEAR).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 4 (FISCAL_YEAR).

Column 3 (`JOBCODE`) does have some commas within the string, however where there are rows with commas in this column they are surrounded by double quotes (") but I think is still causing an issue. Rows 1 and 2 below have commas within the column and are surrounded by double quotes, however row 3 does not have a comma within the JOBCODE column, and therefore does not contain double quotes.

Here is a sample of the CSV input file:

```
11000 - General Hospital,600 - Nursing Admin,"1018 - VP, Nursing Services",FY20,Jul,157,0,0,27,14045,0,0,2440
11000 - General Hospital,600 - Nursing Admin,"1018 - VP, Nursing Services",FY20,Aug,159,0,0,17,14223,0,0,1545
11000 - General Hospital,600 - Nursing Admin,3029 - Clinical Nurse Educator,FY20,May,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: SQL Sevrer 2014 doesn't support quoted strings with `BULK INSERT`. I suggest using something else that does support it, or you'll need to upgrade to SQL Server 2017+ (and use the `FORMAT='CSV'` hint).